# PHP while loop iterates only once

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, iteration

Quick Question;

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cronjobs WHERE status = 0 ");`

```
while($cronjob = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($cronjob['suid'] != $cronjob['cuid']){
        //echo 'not equal<br>';
        $set = 0;
        $sid = $cronjob['sid'];
        $suid = $cronjob['suid'];
        $cuid = $cronjob['cuid'];
        $set = notify($sid, $suid, $cuid);
        if($set==1){
            //echo 'notified<br>';
            $sql = "UPDATE cronjobs SET status = '1' WHERE id='".$cronjob['id']."'";
            if(mysql_query($sql)){
               echo '1<br>';
              $set = 0;
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

`notify()` will `return 1` (numeric)

The problem is only one iteration of the while loop is executed even though there are more records. I don't know what's wrong here. Help me out pls.

Comment: Is your if condition inside while loop true for multiple records?

Comment: @heyanshukla could be. but majority of the records wouldn't be. this just stops after processing one record.

Comment: then first of all echo somethihng out of if condition in while loop.and check the number of iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change inner $sql variable name to something else..outer $sql and inner one are making conflict

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cronjobs WHERE status = 0 ");

while($cronjob = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($cronjob['suid'] != $cronjob['cuid']){
        //echo 'not equal<br>';
        $set = 0;
        $sid = $cronjob['sid'];
        $suid = $cronjob['suid'];
        $cuid = $cronjob['cuid'];
        $set = notify($sid, $suid, $cuid);
        if($set==1){
            //echo 'notified<br>';
            $sql_2 = "UPDATE cronjobs SET status = '1' WHERE id='".$cronjob['id']."'";
            if(mysql_query($sql_2)){
               echo '1<br>';
              $set = 0;
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an observation:

Because you have:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cronjobs WHERE status = 0 ");  
while($cronjob = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

Its going to execute the Query EVERY SINGLE time it goes through the loop. If you have a 100 rows, its going to execute 100 times. If you do this instead, then it executes only once.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cronjobs WHERE status = 0 ");  
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while($cronjob = $res){
```

It wouldnt have conflicted either!

Comment: Its certainly not passed by ref, sir.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly an issue that occurs when you have the same variable for query ($query)
and Result Object ($result).try different name for mysql_query() inside the WHILE Loop.

Comment: This is the same recommendation as the accepted answer.